# Is read/write of a bool value guaranteed to be one instruction in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, types

I can't imagine an architecture would design an access to its smallest data type in multiple instructions, but maybe there is some problem with pipelining that I am not considering?

Comment: Neither C nor C++ have a concept of "instruction", so they can't possibly guarantee anything on this. Plus, "one instruction" and "multiple clock cycles" are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: so we are debating at work


thread foo.....
fooBool = true;

thread bar....
barBool = fooBool;

my contention is that adding mutex protection around this construct is unnecessary as it won't actually guarantee anything addtional.

Comment: I don't know what you're imagining, but "one instruction" is a completely separate thing from "one clock cycle". For most CPUs, most instructions will take multiple cycles.

Comment: you are right Steve, I meant "one instruction" in all places.  Just a lack of proofreading on my part.

Comment: You absolutely do need a mutex, irrespective of whether the `bool` access is one instruction. Among other potential surprises, if you don't use locks then different threads are not guaranteed to see writes from other threads in the same order they were made. Data races are Undefined Behavior: once the code has been mangled by the optimizer all kinds of errors are liable to creep in.

Comment: What are you going to do if you find out that writing to bool takes more than one instruction/clock cycle?

Comment: @SteveJessop For most modern general purpose machines, there is more than one instruction per clock cycle.  In the past, RISC machines had one instruction per clock cycle, CISC machines required several clock cycles for a single instruction---sometimes hundreds, in the case of division.  On modern machines, pipelining  and multiple parallel execution units mean that it's often possible to execute more than one instruction per clock.  Or perhaps more accurately that the concept of doesn't even really have a meaning.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It was more an academic question.  I am fully ready to admit that I was wrong. I still trying to understand exactly what the consequences are of not locking it, because just locking it won't necessarily guarantee the order of operations, and guaranteeing the order isn't necessarily something we need to do.  For larger data structures the problem is easily understandble.

Comment: @SteveJessop, "absolutely do need a mutex", I don't think so. He just needs an atomic operation.

Comment: @Jens: true, there are other ways to ensure atomicity. Of the options he presents in that comment, though, that's the one he needs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whether a `bool` object is read and written in a single operation is ***not guaranteed*** by the C++ standard, because that would put constraints on the underlying hardware, which C and C++ try to minimize.

However, note that in multi-threading scenarios the question whether reading/writing a data type is ***atomic*** is only one half of the problem. The other half is whether changes to some address are ***reflected in all caches*** (i.e. those local to different cores), and whether they are reflected across all threads in the same order. For that you will need memory barriers.

Comment: all the answers have been great so far.  sbi I think you get the nod because you also bring up multi-cores which I hadn't thought of at all.

Comment: I'm pretty sure C++03 doesn't guarantee `sizeof(bool) == sizeof(char)`, does C++11?

Comment: @Steve No. `sizeof(bool)` can be anything.

Answer (score 2):

No it is not guaranteed.

C89 and C99 have no means to express atomicity. C11 has atomic objects.

Compiler usually provide extensions to have atomicity: e.g. for `gcc`:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html

The better is to use some primitives of the `pthreads` library.

Answer (score 0):

for example you have 2 threads which uses same data.

your thread 1 must be as in the followings. lets name is as "i" :

```
while (true) {
           flag[i] = TRUE;
           turn = j;
           while ( flag[j] && turn == j);

                 CRITICAL SECTION

           flag[i] = FALSE;

                   REMAINDER SECTION

   }
```

your thread 2 must be as in the followings. lets name it as "j" :

```
while (true) {
           flag[j] = TRUE;
           turn = i;
           while ( flag[i] && turn == i);

                 CRITICAL SECTION

           flag[i] = FALSE;

                   REMAINDER SECTION

   }
```

flag variable controls the entrance to the critical section for each thread.

the codes runs like :

1- each thread wants to enter critical section by setting its flag true.

2- for example thread "i" gives its pass to thread "j" by setting turn. turn variable stores the thread who entered critical section.

3- since turn variable is capable of storing only one value. it is guarantee that one thread can enter critical section at a time. no other thread can enter critical section if there exists one.

4- thread j sees flag points the pass is its own and wants to enter. therefore it can enter critical section. while thread i waits.

4- after thread j run. it sets its flag variable false by determining itself not to want enter critical section.

5- thread i was held up in the beginning of its while loop.

6- as soon as the thread j gives its turn to other thread by turning its beginning. thread i enters critical section.

this code satisfies. mutex, progress and boundry waiting conditions.

this code can run all environments which supports threading and can be used with any C based language.