# is `memory_order_relaxed` necessary to prevent partial reads of atomic stores

Tags: c++, memory-model, stdatomic

Suppose thread 1 is doing atomic stores on a variable `v` using `memory_order_release` (or any other order) and thread 2 is doing atomic reads on `v` using `memory_order_relaxed`.

It should be impossible to have partial reads in this case. An example of partial reads would be reading the first half of `v` from the latest value and the second half of `v` from the old value.

1. If thread 2 now reads `v` without using atomic operations, can we have partial reads in theory?
2. Can we have partial reads in practice? (Asking because I think this shouldn't matter on most processors, but I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1. how do you propose doing that?

`atomic<T> v` is a template that overloads the `T()` implicit conversion to be like `.load(mo_seq_cst)`.  That makes tearing impossible.  seq_cst atomic is like relaxed plus some ordering guarantees.

The template also overloads operators like `++` to do an atomic `.fetch_add(1, mo_seq_cst)`.  (Or for pre-increment, 1+fetch_add to produce the already-incremented value).

---

**Of course, if you look at the bytes of the object-representation of `atomic<T>` by reading it with non-atomic `char*`** (e.g. with `memcpy(&tmp, &v, sizeof(int))`, **that's UB if another thread is modifying it**.  And yes you can get tearing in practice depending on how you do it.

More likely for objects too large to be lock-free, but possible on some implementations e.g. for 8-byte objects on a 32-bit system which can implement 8-byte atomicity with special instructions, but normally will just use two 32-bit loads.

e.g. 32-bit x86 where an atomic 8-byte load can be done with SSE and then bouncing that back to integer regs.  Or `lock cmpxchg8b`.  Compilers don't do that when they just want two integer registers.

But many 32-bit RISCs that provide atomic 8-byte loads have a double-register load that produces 2 output registers from one instruction.  e.g. ARM `ldrd` or MIPS `ld`.  Compilers *do* use these to optimize aligned 8-byte loads even when atomicity isn't the goal, so you'd probably "get lucky" and not see tearing anyway.

Small objects would typically happen to be atomic anyway; see [Why is integer assignment on a naturally aligned variable atomic on x86?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36624881/why-is-integer-assignment-on-a-naturally-aligned-variable-atomic-on-x86)

---

Of course the non-atomic access wouldn't assume that the value could change asynchronously, so a loop could use a stale value indefinitely.  Unlike a relaxed atomic, which on current compilers is like `volatile` in that it always re-accesses memory.  (Via coherent hardware cache of course, just not keeping the value in a register.)

Comment: Sorry I have missed that part. OTOH I think this is possible to do in C, which also has `stdatomic`. Would the situation be similar to "reading with non-atomic `char*`" then?

Comment: And it sounds like for small objects (e.g. words), tearing would be unlikely in practice?

Comment: @user869887: no, `_Atomic int` in C11 effectively overloads read/write and RMW operators the same way, but inside the compiler because the language itself doesn't support that kind of thing so it can't be a library.  Similar to how `volatile` makes accesses special.

Comment: @user869887: right, small objects would tend to be atomic unless the `memcpy` actually compiled to separate byte loads.  Added a link in the answer

Comment: @user869887 -- when you're writing multi-theaded code, "unlikely in practice" means "will happen, probably when you're giving a demo to your most valuable customer".

Comment: @PeterCordes -- "won't tear" isn't the same as atomic. It's one of the **three** things that C++ atomics guarantee. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624776/can-a-bool-read-write-operation-be-not-atomic-on-x86/14625122#14625122).

Comment: @PeteBecker: lol, yeah.  But in this case it's a compile-time decision.  OTOH it could depend on surrounding code, so a unit test might find no tearing but the asm for the real use-case might be unsafe and harder to test.  Fortunately the OP isn't suggesting you'd ever do this, just wondering what *could* happen.

Comment: @PeteBecker: See last paragraph of this answer.  Note "won't tear" is basically the definition of atomicity.  But yes, `std::atomic` and C11 `_Atomic` give you *more* than just atomicity.  `mo_relaxed` gives you no ordering.  But it does always give you the third thing you mentioned: being sort of like `volatile` and assuming that other threads may have changed the value, so you can't CSE multiple reads.  (The standard doesn't actually rule that out, but compilers don't for QOI reasons: [Why don't compilers merge redundant std::atomic writes?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45960387)).

Comment: @PeteBecker I agree. Not going to cut corners here. Just checking my understanding : )

Comment: @PeterCordes Just to double check, if I do some operation on an atomic variable without specifying the ordering (e.g. `v++`), then `memory_order_seq_cst` is used in both C/C++? What if `v` is a pointer and an assignment is done (`v = ptr`)? I imagine this is the case as non-explicit functions use `memory_order_seq_cst` by default, and the first part of your answer seems to suggest the same.

Comment: @user869887: yes, seq_cst is the default for everything; you have to explicitly specify a weaker memory order if you want less ordering.  `atomic<T*>` doesn't make anything different; it's still an atomic seq-cst assignment of the pointer *value* to the atomic pointer object.  Or do you mean `atomic<T> *v`? In that case it's just a normal assignment of a pointer *to* an atomic object, and `v` is not itself atomic.

Comment: @PeterCordes I meant `atomic<T*>`. Sorry for the confusion and thanks again!

Comment: In C++20, you could do what the OP suggests (access a value both atomically and not) with `std::atomic_ref`.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: Yup.  I was prepared for their answer to "how do you propose doing that" to be "with `std::atomic_ref`", but since not it might have been more confusing.  Side note, I think `std::atomic_ref` is going to introduce a lot of confusion on ABIs where `alignof(T) < alignof(atomic<T>)` for types like `uint64_t`; people will just expect that they can atomic_ref an arbitrary `uint64_t` but if the implementation isn't careful that can introduce tearing in loads/stores.  related: GCC still hasn't fixed their C11 `_Atomic uint64_t` to enforce 8-byte alignment inside structs.